# How to get new users for an Office 365 tenant through Graph API?

Tags: office-365, active-directory, azure

I'm looking for a way to retrieve new users to my tenant. I am polling users through the Graph API,

[msdn article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)

Now, this API doesn't list any created datetime or anything similar. I am trying to find an API query that would fetch new users to the system after a certain date time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you dirsyncing users to your tenant? You could key off the lastDirSyncTime  and possibly look for some other blank AD attribute to determine new users https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#UserEntity

Comment: @EricAlexander No we aren't. 

dirSyncEnabled": null,
"lastDirSyncTime": null,

is what we get in the metadata for our users.

Comment: So you are strictly all cloud users, *.onmicrosoft.com accounts?

Comment: Actually we have a couple of tenants. Most are on the shared cloud. But a couple of tenants with on premises setup (i.e, not the shared cloud)

Comment: I think you're going to have to look for an attribute that is null and settable and won't be used for anything, query against that, do your other updates as required, then set that field to something so it isn't picked up again. maybe something like userType.

Comment: @EricAlexander I tried that approach but it doesn't seem to work for UserType as it specifically requires Guest/Member values. Plus this is customer data so we are reluctant in modifying their data for our processing purposes.

Comment: @EricAlexander Tried this with other fields but the problem is the filter query, for example if I selecte 'jobTitle' for this purpose, the issue is the datatype, all of these are STRING type. Now the fields which are DateTime type are non filterable/modifiable. Plus it doesn't support a "ne" (not equals) option. Otherwise, we'd have thought about going with this approach.